# Eigenvalues of matrix with submatrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hermitian-matrices

So, I was doing homework and I had to turn an arbitrary invertible $N \times N$ matrix $A$ into a Hermitian $2N \times 2N$ matrix $A'$. This is rather simple, namely pick $A' = \begin{pmatrix} 
O & A^* \\
A & O\\
\end{pmatrix}$.
However, I got curious about the eigenvalues. Are the eigenvalues of $A'$ easy to calculate from $A$? I personally expect so. Since the eigenvalues of $A^*$ are the complex conjugates of those of $A$, I thought this could somehow but used, but I am not entirely sure.

So, would this be possible?

Comment: the eigenvalues of $A'$ are plus or minus the singular values of $A$

Comment: Oh really? Is there a simple reason why that is?

Comment: try computing $\text{trace}\big((A')^k\big)$ first for odd $k$, then for even $k$

Answer (score 0):

Observe that \begin{align*}
\det(A' - \lambda I) &= \det \begin{pmatrix} - \lambda I & A^* \\ A & - \lambda I \end{pmatrix} \\
&= \det(\lambda^2 I - A^* A)
\end{align*}
That is, the eigenvalues of $A'$ are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $A^* A = A^2$, which are precisely the singular values of $A$.

Comment: "These are in fact the absolute values of the eigenvalues of A"

Ugh oh, you might want to think about this.

Comment: Why are we just allowed to calculate the determinant like that even though the entries are matrices? Like, won't we get a different term than $\lambda^2$ since there are many more lambda?

Comment: You can compute the determinant by block as long as they commute

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Whoops, thanks. Got confused with what was Hermitian and what wasn't.